# Can I use Factory service functions inside the factory service?

Tags: angularjs, angular-services

For example we have this factory service , this service will get and set the firstname of the user.

```
app.factory('userService',['$rootScope',function($rootScope){
      var user = {};
      return {

          getFirstname : function () {
            return user.firstname;
          },

          setFirstname : function (firstname) {
            user.firstname = firstname;
            $rootScope.$broadcast("updates");
          }

        }
        }]);
```

Can I use getFirstname function inside this service?? If I can, then can you show me how to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can if you break your javascript into pieces.  Instead of defining the function inside the return object, just assign it to a variable beforehand.  Then you can use the function inside the factory.  Just remember to assign the function to your return object at the end.

```
app.factory('userService', ['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {
    var user = {};
    var getFirst = function() {
        return user.firstname;
    };
    //Do anything else with getFirst

    return {
        getFirstname: getFirst, //assign the function to the factory return obj

        setFirstname: function(firstname) {
            user.firstname = firstname;
            $rootScope.$broadcast("updates");
        }
    };
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a better way to keep the service code organized and clean.

CoffeeScript:

```
app.factory 'userService', [
  '$rootScope'
  ($rootScope) ->
    service = 
      user: null

      getFirstName: ->
        service.user.firstname

      getLastName: ->
        service.user.firstname

      setFirstName: (firstname) ->
        service.user.firstname = firstname
        $rootScope.$broadcast 'updates'
        return

      getDisplayName: ->
        service.getFirstName() + service.getLastName()
]
```

Javascript:

```
app.factory('userService', ['$rootScope', function($rootScope){
  var service = {
    user: null,

    getFirstName : function () {
      return service.user.firstname;
    },

    getLastName : function () {
      return service.user.firstname;
    },

    setFirstName : function (firstname) {
      service.user.firstname = firstname;
      $rootScope.$broadcast("updates");
    },

    getDisplayName: function() {
      return service.getFirstName() + service.getLastName();
    }
  }
  return service;
}]);
```